# Parallel port in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone help me in our thesis?

How will I send data or signal to H-Bridge then to DC Motor using parallel port in vb.net?

Comment: Shop for the parallel I/O hardware first.  Whatever you'll find will have a driver with it that will make it usable from a program.  Either through pinvoke or a .NET wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Parallel Device driver in [Chris Cant's Writing Windows WDM Device Drivers book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0879305657) with success and have also used the [inpout32.dll](http://www.logix4u.net/) mentioned in below Code Project articles. There may be limitations on operating system and bus type. i.e Windows XP and ISA (its been a few years).

Also look at these CodeProject articles:

1. [I/O Ports Uncensored - 1 - Controlling LEDs (Light Emiting Diodes) with Parallel Port](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csppleds.aspx?q=writing%20to%20the%20parallel%20port%20in%20.net)
2. [I/O Ports Programming (Parallel port) Reading / Writing + Surveillance System using VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/PortAccess.aspx?q=writing%20to%20the%20parallel%20port%20in%20.net)

Comment: i've seen the link that you have sent to me. it helps me a lot. but do have any idea in coding regarding in the topic that i have been asking. i hope you can help me. thanks in advance!.

Comment: The links should show you how to use the Parallel Port driver, I do not have a **data sheet** or a **manual** on the specific device(s) you are trying to interface to. I have used both drivers that I mentioned with success interfacing to I/O modules in the past.

Answer (score 0):

okay the parallel printer port on a pc is, in its simplest form an 8 bit output device.  Drivers etc vary so this is psudo code to be adapted to your needs.

```
Const fw as byte = 0 ' freewheel
Const cw as byte = 1 ' clockwise
Const ccw as byte = 2 ' counter clockwise
Const bk as byte = 3 ' brake
Const en as byte = 4 ' output enable

Sub BtnCW_click
  Parallelport.output(cw or en)  ' turn clockwise and send enable
End sub
```

Connect the A input on the hbridge to bit 0 of the port, Connect the B input of the hbridge to bit 1 of the port, and bit 2 of the port to the enable input of the hbridge.  The gnd connection of the port must be connected to the gnd on the hbridge.

Obviously you need to setup a library to access the port, if you decide which library you wish to use and what hbridge you are using then I can be much more helpful, but you havnt provided much to go on.

Comment: how to declare the parallel port?